# mouse right-click contextMenuStrip doesn't show ONLY for the first time

Tags: c#, datagridview, mouseevent, contextmenustrip

I got this part of code, where I open contextMenuStrip in respond to mouse right-click (over dataGridView table).

The problem is, that the FIRST TIME i right click - the menu doesn't pop up. On the second time it pops up, and since then everything is working well..

```
    private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView.HitTestInfo info = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y); //get info
        int currentMouseOverRow = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) //MouseButton right: Open context menu strip.
         {
             dataGridView1.Rows[currentMouseOverRow].Selected = true; //Select the row

             ContextMenuStrip Menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
             ToolStripMenuItem MenuOpenPO = new ToolStripMenuItem("Delete it");
             MenuOpenPO.Click += new EventHandler(MenuOpenPO_Click);
             Menu.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { MenuOpenPO });
             dataGridView1.ContextMenuStrip = Menu; //Assign to dataGridView1
         }
    }
```

Any help ? :) I use visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Problem :** You have added `ContextMenu` to the `DataGridView` after `RightClick` event. so `ContextMenu` willbe added to your `DataGridView` after the first `RightClick` hence user can see the attached `ContextMenu` from the further `RightClick` events.

**Solution :** you need to add the `ContextMenu` before right clicking on the `DataGridView` so that it will be appeared for each `RightClick` event.

**Note :** if `ContextMenu` is assigned to any control , it willbe displayed on `rightclick` by default, means you do not need to add it for each `RightClick` event on the control explicitly.

Try This: in `Form Load` Event

```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
        ContextMenuStrip Menu = new ContextMenuStrip();
        ToolStripMenuItem MenuOpenPO = new ToolStripMenuItem("Delete it");
        MenuOpenPO.Click += new EventHandler(MenuOpenPO_Click);
        Menu.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { MenuOpenPO });
        dataGridView1.ContextMenuStrip = Menu; //Assign to dataGridView1
    }
```

Comment: Oh, wow. That explains a lot. Thanks for this. And the menu is easily disabled by disabling the control it's bound to.

Answer (score 1):

I typically create a `ContextMenuStrip` object of my own (private variable) and `Show()` it when needed.  I suspect that it's being *assigned* the first time, but cannot display because the newly added menu doesn't get its own right-click trigger to display.  That only happens the second time, once it exists.

Like this:
    private ContextMenuStrip _myMenu;

```
private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView.HitTestInfo info = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y); //get info
    int currentMouseOverRow = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;

    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right) //MouseButton right: Open context menu strip.
     {
         dataGridView1.Rows[currentMouseOverRow].Selected = true; //Select the row

         _myMenu = new ContextMenuStrip();
         ToolStripMenuItem MenuOpenPO = new ToolStripMenuItem("Delete it");
         MenuOpenPO.Click += new EventHandler(MenuOpenPO_Click);
         _myMenu.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { MenuOpenPO });
         _myMenu.Show(new Point(e.X, e.Y));
     }
}
```

Comment: +1 You should dispose the old menu when it is no more needed, else I suppose you'd leak resource

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Leak what?  It's a local object with scope to the parent (a `Form` I presume).  The fact that it's being initialized each time is not indicative of multiple instances.

Comment: You'll leak a `UserObject`, I mean a control, in this case `ContextMenuStrip`. Control will not be garbage collected if left unreferenced, `ContextMenuStrip` is also a control. You're creating `_myMenu = new ContextMenuStrip();` new instance, where are you disposing it?

Comment: Explicit disposal is normally not needed; once no longer show, the old object is unreferenced, and will be cleaned up by the garbage collector.