# Why ContextMenuStrip is not opening at first time click from a button in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenustrip

I am currently developing a Matrix(layout) Popup Menu using a `Form`. Inside the popup menu, there's a `Button`. The button should open a `ContextMenuStrip` when left clicked, but not right clicked. With that, I didn't assign the `ContextMenuStrip` to the `ContextMenuStrip` properties of the button, in the `Design` panel of the Microsoft Visual Studio. Just for your information, the `ContextMenuStrip`'s location is directly under the `Button`.

Below are the examples to help you to visualize.

- This is how the Matrix Popup Menu looks like:
  [image: the popup menu]
- This is how the `Button` should look like with the `ContextMenuStrip`opened:
  [image: the cs]

As the title suggests, I can't open the `ContextMenuStrip` at the first click of the button. It however works on the next clicks. I've tried solution(s) from these links, but to no avail:

1. [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20774671/mouse-right-click-contextmenustrip-doesnt-show-only-for-the-first-time).
2. [Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46634258/contextmenustrip-not-showing-on-the-first-time-of-being-right-clicked).
3. [Solution 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65838424/contextmenustrip-requires-two-right-clicks-to-display).

Below are the codes involved(all inside of `MatrixPopupMenu.cs`):

```
//global variable
private Point contextStripLocation;

//zoomFactorContextStrip -> name of the ContextMenuStrip object

//the button's click event handler
private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if((e as MouseEventArgs).Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        zoomFactorContextStrip.Show(button15, contextStripLocation);
    }
}

//matrix popup menu's load event handler
private void MatrixPopupMenu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    contextStripLocation = new Point(0, this.button15.Height);
}
```

May I know what can I do to fix this, please?

Comment: Try using `MouseUp` event instead of click.

Comment: @PoulBak Result is still the same. The matrix popup menu will only be shown on the next mouseup event, but not the first one.

Comment: @PoulBak 's comment was helpful, so, +1. Thank God, I managed to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was messing around with the `MouseUp` and `MouseDown` event handlers, I somehow managed to fix my own issue.

Simply, I just need two things:

1. In the `MouseDown` event handler, the `ContextMenuStrip.Close()` is called.
2. In the `MouseUp` event handler, the `ContextMenuStrip.Show()` is called.

Below are the codes:

```
//global variable
private Point contextStripLocation;

//zoomFactorContextStrip -> name of the ContextMenuStrip object

//the button's click event handler
//private void button15_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) -> not used anymore

//instead, replaced with:
//popup menu's mouseup event handler
private void button15_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        this.TopMost = true;
        zoomFactorContextStrip.Show(button15, zoomFactorCSLocation);
    }
}

//popup menu's mousedown event handler
private void button15_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    zoomFactorContextStrip.Close();
}

//matrix popup menu's load event handler
private void MatrixPopupMenu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    contextStripLocation = new Point(0, this.button15.Height);
}
```

To be exact and honest, I don't really know why this works, but it completely solves my issue. It maybe somehow related to [Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46634258/contextmenustrip-not-showing-on-the-first-time-of-being-right-clicked).